# How to prove that these metrics induces the same topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X_i,d_i), i\in \mathbb{N}$ be a countably infinite familiy of metric spaces

$e\left( \prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i,  \prod_{i=1}^\infty b_i  \right)   = sup\{d_i(a_i,b_i):i\in \mathbb{N}\}$

with $d_i(a,b) \leq 1$ for all $a,b \in X_i $

Prove that this metric is equivalent to

$d\left( \prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i,  \prod_{i=1}^\infty b_i  \right)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{d_i(a_i,b_i)}{2^i}$

What I know to do is:

Let $y\in B_e(x,r)$ where $x=\prod_{i=1}^\infty x_i$ and $y=\prod_{i=1}^\infty y_i$. Thus $sup\{d_i(x_i,y_i):i\in \mathbb{N}\}<r$. If $sup\{d_i(x_i,y_i):i\in \mathbb{N}\}=1$ (and $r>1$) it is easy to see that $d(x,y)\leq e(x,y)$ because $d$ is bounded above by $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}=1$ and so $B_d(x,r)\subseteq B_e(x,r)$.

If $sup\{d_i(x_i,y_i):i\in \mathbb{N}\}<1$, I convinced myself that I get to the same result.

Now, I can't see that if $y\in B_d(x,r)$ then $B_e(x,r)\subseteq B_d(x,r)$, I am not convinced that this can be true. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1). General remark. For any   metrics $d,e$ on a set $X ,$ let $S(d,e)$ be the statement:  For every $x\in X$ and every $r>0$ there exists $s>0$ such that  $B_e(x,s)\subset B_d(x,r).$

So  $S(d,e)$ implies that every open $d$-ball is a union of open $e$-balls. So if $S(d,e)$ and $S(e,d)$, then $d,e$ are equivalent.

(2).For your Q: $$y\in B_e(x,r)\implies \forall i\;(d_i(x_i,y_i)<r)\implies d(x,y)<r\implies y\in B_d(x,r).$$ So $B_e(x,r)\subset B_d(x,r).$

So we have $S(d,e).$ (With $s=r$).

But $d$ and $e$ are NOT generally equivalent.

For example let $X_i=\{0,1\}$ and $d_i(0,1)=1$ for every $i.$ Then for every $x\in X=\prod_iX_i$ we have $B_e(x,1)=\{x\}$.

So every subset of $X$ is $e$-open and $e$-closed.

But for $x=(x_i)_i\in X,$ and for $n\in \mathbb N$, let $y_{i,n}=x_i$ for $i\ne n$ and $y_{n,n}=1-x_n,$ and let $y(n)=(y_{i,n})_i.$ Then $y(n)\ne x$ for every $n,$ but $$d(x,y(n))=2^{-n}.$$ So $\{y(n):n\in \mathbb N\}$ is not $d$-closed.